# Creating a hole into which an object can be pushed

Tags: openscad

I have an [object](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4090) and want to construct a part that the object could be slotted into along the Y-axis.

[image: object to be slotted]

If I just subtract the object, I will end up with a hollow that is bigger on the inside so it will not be possible to push the object in.

I would like it if there was an easy way to construct the red “hull” so that it can be subtracted from the purple cube.

[image: side view of the desired shape]

One possibility seems to be the extrusion of a projection of the object into the Y-plane, though that also includes the pins, which would be too much – those are only at the end.

[image: attempt by extruding a projection]

Is there some combination/operation that allows “subtraction by imprinting”?

Comment: Try extruding only faces pointed in -y direction, and using the resulting object in a boolean operation.

Comment: @Ezra how would I get just the faces pointed in -y direction?

Comment: In the end, I just added a `showPins` parameter to the module and pass `false` to it when extruding.